# Get the name of child class inside of super class

Tags: puppet

is there a way to get the name of a child class inside of a super class?

```
class ChildClass inherits SuperClass { }

class SuperClass {
    notify { "$NAME_OF_CHILD_CLASS is inheriting me": }
}
```

The expected output would be `ChildClass is inheriting me`. I'd need something similar to `$module_name` which contains the name of the class that contains the current resource's definition.

Is there a way to achieve this? I don't mind if I need a custom function for that...

Comment: wanting this is indicative of that you're wanting to break Liskov's substitution principle

Comment: not necessarily. Ruby for example offers `self.descendants`.

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to accomplish is possible.
I do know it's not worth trying.  Any time you find yourself inheriting another class, there is almost always a better way to do it without inheriting.  I honestly can't think of an instance where inheritance would be good.

Comment: @rojs that's actually a good answer.